# Trouble getting a list of trip paths in Prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, transitive-closure

I am having trouble with the following problem in Prolog, I have several facts in a knowledge base for example:

```
flight(rome,london,ba,1500,150,400).
flight(london,newyork,airfrance,600,60,200).
flight(rome,paris,airfrance,1200,120,500).  
flight(paris,newyork,airfrance,600,60,200).
flight(newyork,london,ba,1500,240,300).
```

I am only interested in getting a list of all possible routes from X to Y. I understand that I must use a recursive rule and that I have to add the places visited to a list to stop the cycle running over and over as the flight paths in the knowledge base have several cycles.

what I have so far is:

```
flight_route(X,Y):-
   flight(X,Y,A,B,C,D).

trip(X,X,[]).
trip(X,Z,T) :-
   flight_route(Y,Z),
   not(member(Y,T)),
   trip(X,Y,[Y|T]).
```

for some reason, when I look at the trace, the rule is failing when it tries to check that not(member(Y,T)) but I cant understand why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

More generally,

```
trip(X,Y) :-
   closure0(flight_route,X,Y).
```

See [the definition of `closure0/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26946133/772868)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your definition of the `trip/3` predicate. Try:

```
trip(X, X, _).
trip(X, Z, T) :-
   flight_route(X, Y),
   \+ member(Y, T),
   trip(Y, Z, [Y| T]).
```

In the first clause, when you're at your destination, it doesn't matter how you got there. Hence the (anonymous) variable in the third argument. Also, is likely more efficient to find a path starting from the origin point rather then the destination point. A possible issue might also be how you're calling the `trip/3` predicate. Be sure to call it with an empty list passed on the third argument (if you don't ground `T`, the call `\+ member(Y, T)` will always fail). Or define a `trip/2` argument to abstract that implementation detail:

```
trip(X, Y) :-
    trip(X, Y, []).
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I can see how your suggestion makes sense, but one thing that I am not sure of is how to write the list T. After making the changes you suggested I can query for example (rome,newyork). which returns True. However I am unsure how to return and write to the console all the possibilities of the list T. When I query (rome,newyork,T). I am getting a False result. Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: Hint: you could use an **additional** argument to return the path between two connected airports. The (current) list argument is just to avoid cycles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Paulo. I think I got it now.